# How to backup Windows Phone 7 apps & data on a Mac?

Tags: macos, backup, windows-phone

I'm using a Windows Phone 7 phone, syncing it with my Mac. Is there any way to back it up on the Mac, so that I could restore it to factory settings, then have it automatically reinstall apps and their data, like iTunes can do for an iPhone?  Is this available in the Zune software for Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Only thing I could find.

> **[Windows Phone 7 Connector (for Mac) - Beta](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=1fe7ea0f-3ad6-4137-8397-d412a3792c33)**

Comment: I'm already using that, but I don't think it does backups.  I love this quote from the overview though - "In order to enjoy the Zune experience on Mac, you will need to install a Windows OS (XP or higher)."

Comment: Yeah, use boot camp, or parallels. Since Mac and MS are on opposite sides of the camp, they are not going to make their devices work to well on each others OS.

Comment: The Mac Connector is the only thing from Microsoft that is available for WP7 for OSX users...

Answer (score 0):

Backup is not a feature of the Zune software, for Windows Phone 7 devices; i.e. this isn't possible on PCs either.

Comment: Not entirely true. It will automatically occur when applying OS updates.

Comment: But it's tied to the OS at time to backup; it ultimately has no value to the user until homebrew tools come out to extract that data. (They don't exist at time of writing.)